# Installed Celery but it does not implement tasks

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, celery

I,m using Amazon web services. And I'm trying to make Celery work.
Tried to do what the documentation says (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#configuring-your-django-project-to-use-celery), but when I start celery worker and try to call a task nothing happens, as if there were no task.

Here's my settings.py file:

```
import os
import djcelery
import djkombu
import sys
import tasks
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())

djcelery.setup_loader()

# Django settings for analogg project.

DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
     ('Nikita', 'bodnarnikita@gmail.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'analoggdb',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/static/'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = 'http://analogg.info/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'analogg.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'analogg.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    "/templates/",
    "/home/ubuntu/analogg/templates",
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

INSTALLED_APPS += ('djcelery', )
#INSTALLED_APPS += ('djkombu', )

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"

CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS = True
CELERY_DISABLE_RATE_LIMITS = True
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("analogg.tasks", )

#BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/'
#BROKER_BACKEND = "djkombu.transport.DatabaseTransport"


# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

This is my views.py file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.template import Context, loader, RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from tasks import parsesob, add
from parsersob import parser
import os, random, string

def index(request):
    html = "<html><body>Hello, world!</body></html>"
    add.apply_async(args=[id, '23bnn'])
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

This is my tasks.py file:

```
from celery.decorators import task
from celery.task.schedules import crontab
from parsersob import parser
#from parsersob2 import parser2
from celery import Celery

#celery = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://rabbitmqprelaunch9176@ip-10-117-81-80//')

@task
def add(id, a1, a2):
    f = open('add.txt', 'w')
    g = a1 + a2
    f.write(g)
    f.close()
```

And this is my celeryconfig.py file being in the same folder with tasks.py, settings.py and views.py:

```
#BROKER_URL = 'amqp://'
#CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'analoggdb'
#BROKER_URL = "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//"
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("analogg.tasks", )
#CELERY_RESULT_DBURI = "sqlite:///analoggdb.db"

CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
```

I'm a newbie, so could anyone please tell me what to do to make it work.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

UPD:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-117-81-80:/var/log/apache2$ sudo rabbitmqctl status
Status of node 'rabbit@ip-10-117-81-80' ...
[{pid,849},
 {running_applications,[{rabbit,"RabbitMQ","2.7.1"},
                        {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.2.7"},
                        {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","2.1.10"},
                        {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.5"},
                        {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","1.17.5"},
                        {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.14.5"}]},
 {os,{unix,linux}},
 {erlang_version,"Erlang R14B04 (erts-5.8.5) [source] [64-bit] [rq:1] [async-threads:30] [kernel-poll:true]\n"},
 {memory,[{total,25494568},
          {processes,11083752},
          {processes_used,11077008},
          {system,14410816},
          {atom,1124433},
          {atom_used,1120234},
          {binary,89696},
          {code,11134393},
          {ets,752120}]},
 {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.3999999990304762},
 {vm_memory_limit,247544217}]
...done.
```

The output of running celeryd:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-117-81-80:~/analogg$ python manage.py celeryd worker --loglevel=info

 -------------- celery@ip-10-117-81-80 v3.0.3 (Chiastic Slide)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- [Configuration]
-- * - **** --- . broker:      amqp://guest@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- . app:         default:0x13c2a90 (djcelery.loaders.DjangoLoader)
- ** ---------- . concurrency: 1 (processes)
- ** ---------- . events:      OFF (enable -E to monitor this worker)
- ** ---------- 
- *** --- * --- [Queues]
-- ******* ---- . celery:      exchange:celery(direct) binding:celery
--- ***** ----- 

[Tasks]
  . analogg.tasks.add
  . analogg.tasks.parsesob

[2012-07-22 06:24:30,336: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@ip-10-117-81-80 has started.
```

UPD:

```
    [Sun Jul 22 08:10:58 2012] [error] [client 37.110.0.126] mod_wsgi (pid=7411): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/analogg/apache/django.wsgi'.
[Sun Jul 22 08:10:58 2012] [error] [client 37.110.0.126] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Jul 22 08:10:58 2012] [error] [client 37.110.0.126]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
[Sun Jul 22 08:10:58 2012] [error] [client 37.110.0.126]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Sun Jul 22 08:10:58 2012] [error] [client 37.110.0.126]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 82, in get_response
[Sun Jul 22 08:10:58 2012] [error] [client 37.110.0.126]     urlconf = settings.ROOT_URLCONF
[Sun Jul 22 08:10:58 2012] [error] [client 37.110.0.126]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 185, in inner
[Sun Jul 22 08:10:58 2012] [error] [client 37.110.0.126]     return func(self._wrapped, *args)
[Sun Jul 22 08:10:58 2012] [error] [client 37.110.0.126] AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'ROOT_URLCONF'
[Sun Jul 22 08:10:58 2012] [error] [client 37.110.0.126] mod_wsgi (pid=7377): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/analogg/apache/django.wsgi'.
[Sun Jul 22 08:10:58 2012] [error] [client 37.110.0.126] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Jul 22 08:10:58 2012] [error] [client 37.110.0.126]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
[Sun Jul 22 08:10:58 2012] [error] [client 37.110.0.126]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Sun Jul 22 08:10:58 2012] [error] [client 37.110.0.126]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 82, in get_response
[Sun Jul 22 08:10:58 2012] [error] [client 37.110.0.126]     urlconf = settings.ROOT_URLCONF
[Sun Jul 22 08:10:58 2012] [error] [client 37.110.0.126]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 185, in inner
[Sun Jul 22 08:10:58 2012] [error] [client 37.110.0.126]     return func(self._wrapped, *args)
[Sun Jul 22 08:10:58 2012] [error] [client 37.110.0.126] AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'ROOT_URLCONF'
```

Comment: Since you've commented the line `#BROKER_URL = 'amqp://'`, what broker do you use then?

Comment: I was just experimenting with celeryconfig.py. I know, it is supposed not to be commented. But even if I leave it uncommented still nothing happens.

Comment: The question is do you have a queue backend installed and running - like RabbitMQ(which is a hard job to install on Amazon instances) or similar? In order the task to be run, it needs to be queued in a broker. Try setting `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True` in the config and see if it works...

Comment: Yes, it is running. I added an update to my post, showing the response to command rabbitmqctl status

Comment: Did you run celeryd ? `python manage.py celeryd --someoptions...` ? And if yes - what's the output there?

Comment: You shouldn't `import tasks` in your `settings.py`, especially if that  module creates tasks or load anything Django related.

Comment: Remember that when you import things in settings, that means that the modules will be loaded when Django has not been properly set up yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what is the problem here, but here is an example config, that works:

This is located at the end of settings.py:

```
#CELERY CONFIG
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()

BROKER_HOST = "Host"
BROKER_PORT = "Port"
BROKER_USER = "User"
BROKER_PASSWORD = "Pass"
BROKER_VHOST = "VHost"

CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = "some_queue"
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE = "some_exc"
```

The broker's user/pass/vhost are configured using the [rabbitmqctl tool](http://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html)

You can trace the queue/exchange with

```
rabbitmqadmin get queue="some_queue"
```

NOTE: It is very useful to track the logs in `/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log` or whatever the log file is. This will show you if there is a problem with the connection to RabbitMQ, like wrong credentials, permissions, etc.

Comment: Do you guess that the problem is in rabbitmq settings?

Comment: As I see the other settings look fine. I've spent lots of time once  debugging a situation like this, and finally it was a permissions problem. So look at rabbitmq logs - it will give you the needed info if the problem is there.

Comment: A good explanation here: http://sakaijunsoccer.appspot.com/media/img/skills/program/RabbitMQ.txt

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but now I get server 500 error.

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"

CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS = True
CELERY_DISABLE_RATE_LIMITS = True
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("analogg.tasks", )
BROKER_HOST = "localhost"
BROKER_PORT = "5672"
BROKER_USER = "guest"
BROKER_PASSWORD = ""
BROKER_VHOST = "rabbit"

CELERY_ROUTES = ('FILE_WITH_ROUTES',)

Comment: Now I get: Unrecoverable error: OSError(12, 'Cannot allocate memory'). Server error in update

Comment: Is there anything in the rabbitmq log? Also try adding only these into settings.py: `import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
BROKER_HOST = "localhost"
BROKER_PORT = 5672
BROKER_USER = "guest"
BROKER_PASSWORD = "guest"
BROKER_VHOST = "/"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "amqp"
CELERYD_LOG_FILE = "celeryd.log"
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL = "INFO"
`

Comment: Here's the latest in rabbit log, but it is an old error

=ERROR REPORT==== 22-Jul-2012::12:37:04 ===
exception on TCP connection <0.622.0> from 127.0.0.1:55078
{channel0_error,opening,
                {amqp_error,access_refused,
                            "access to vhost 'rabbit' refused for user 'guest'",
                            'connection.open'}}

=INFO REPORT==== 22-Jul-2012::12:37:04 ===
closing TCP connection <0.622.0> from 127.0.0.1:55078

Comment: Just revert all changes from the initial state, and add only the settings from my previous comment here.... The error says that guest has no access to VHOST='rabbit'. Use the default guest/guest, or better just create new user.. But The OSError above is strange for me. There could be lots of reasons for it... You need to debug a bit and make it work... Can't help much with this error ..

Comment: Probably not. From what I see - djcelery tries to connect to RabbitMQ, which is good. You just need to clean all unnecessary things from settings.py and to make it work using *valid* BROKER_[USER/PASS/VHOST] settings.

Comment: Ok, but now i get this:


ubuntu@ip-10-117-81-80:~/analogg$ sudo rabbitmqctl add_user celery nikita
Creating user "celery" ...
Error: unable to connect to node 'rabbit@ip-10-117-81-80': nodedown
diagnostics:
- nodes and their ports on ip-10-117-81-80: [{rabbit,53335},
                                             {rabbitmqctl9982,40364}]
- current node: 'rabbitmqctl9982@ip-10-117-81-80'
- current node home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- current node cookie hash: zNiwW+qJHs2e9AjWqb5uXw==
[1]   Killed                  python manage.py celeryd

Comment: It seems something killed the rabbitmq node.. Restart it, and make sure to add VALID user/pass/vhost in settings.py.

Comment: I get error when I restart it.

'Error: unable to connect to node 'rabbit@ip-10-117-81-80': nodedown
diagnostics:
- nodes and their ports on ip-10-117-81-80: [{rabbit,53335},
                                             {rabbitmqctl10275,47489}]
- current node: 'rabbitmqctl10275@ip-10-117-81-80'
- current node home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- current node cookie hash: zNiwW+qJHs2e9AjWqb5uXw==
ubuntu@ip-10-117-81-80:~/analogg$'